# Mudar cor de letra de uma célula Tabela com ajax

Tags: ajax, table

Digamos que eu tenha a seguinte tabela:

[image: Tabela de Usuários]

Eu tenho uma opção que clico para ativar os usuários selecionados pelas checkbox. Tudo já funcionando e inclusive ocorre a ativação dos usuários. estou utilizando Ajax fazendo o browser se comunicar com o servidor e ativar usuário sem ter de carregar a página toda de novo. 
Minha única dúvida é a seguinte: Após usuário ser ativo quero que  mudasse a célula marcada do campo Status para: Ativo e cor Verde. Teria como?

Já fiz algo com `addClass('Ativo')` porém só consegui deixar todas as palavras da linha em verde. Gostaria que apenas a célula alterasse para ativo e com cor verde.

Por enquanto tenho isto em meu código:

```
$('i.icon-check').closest('li').click(fnAtivar);

function fnAtivar() {
    var paraAtivar = $('#tableUsuario tr input:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
        return {
            cod_user: this.value,
            tr: $(this).closest('tr').get()
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "ativarUsuario.php",
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            codigosAtivar: paraAtivar.map(function () {
                return this.cod_user
            }).get()
        },
        success: function (resposta) {
        resposta = JSON.parse(resposta);
         console.log(resposta, typeof resposta, typeof resposta[0], resposta[1]);
        if (resposta[0]) paraAtivar.each(function(){
            //aqui acredito que vai o código para realizar a alteração
        });
        alert(resposta[1]);
    }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente fazer isso:

```
if (resposta[0]) {
      var tabela = $('#tableUsuario tr');

      $.each(tabela, function(index, tr) {
        var checkbox = $(tr).find("input:checkbox");
        if ($(checkbox).is(':checked')) {
          $(tr).find(".status").text("Ativado");
          $(tr).find(".status").css("color", "#51A351");
        } else {
          $(tr).find(".status").text("Inativo");
          $(tr).find(".status").css("color", "#BD362F");
        }
      });
    }
```

Lembrando que em toda td que tiver o status, deve ter a class `class='status'`

Comment: Em que local coloco isto no código? tenho que remover algo existente? @Antony Alkmim

Comment: Troca o loop if (resposta[0]) paraAtivar.each(function(){
            //aqui acredito que vai o código para realizar a alteração
        }); e coloca esse que coloquei na resposta,

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. @Bacco xD

Comment: Coloquei, porém não aconteceu nada além de mostrar o alerta. No caso esta `resposta` ela vem da outra página assim `[true, Usuário ativado com sucesso!]`. Em uma função para excluir usuário eu utilizava isto `this.tr[0].remove();` e aqui neste seu código é `$(tr).` - Digo isto, por que pode auxiliar para chegarmos a um resultado.

Comment: Cara, ele já está escrevendo `Ativado`. . Agora falta só trocar a cor, que não está fazendo com este código :D

Comment: Eu alterei a resposta ali, tente colocar a class status na td que for informar se esta ativo ou inativo, eu usei $(tr) porque o $.each(tabela,function(index,elemento){}); funciona assim, ele vai fazer um loop por todos os elementos da tabela e retornar o index que se refere ao indice, e o elemento que se refere no caso cada tr dentro da tabela,no caso eu chamei a variavel elemento de tr pra melhor entendimento.

Comment: Cara, ele já está escrevendo `Ativado`. . Agora falta só trocar a cor, que não está fazendo com este código :D

Comment: Voce quer mudar a cor do que? tr?td?texto dentro da td?

Comment: do Texto `Ativado`

Comment: basta colocar $(tr).find(".status").css('color',"#CODIGODACOR");

Comment: Sim, já tinha me ligado e feito. Deu certo :D

Comment: Tem outra coisa - na `td` ao lado eu tenho um icone (link) para Desativar também. Queria que ao mesmo tempo que estas alterações ocorrem, o icone troque para outro que desativa.

`if($escrever['status_user']=='ativo'|| $escrever['status_user']=='Ativo')
          {
              echo "<a href=\"desativarUsuario.php?cod=".$escrever['cod_user']."\"> <i class=\"icon-ban-circle\" title=\"Desativar Usuário!\"></i></a>";
          }else{
           echo "<a href=\"ativarUsuario.php?cod=".$escrever['cod_user']."\"> <i class=\"icon-check\" title=\"Ativar Usuário!\"></i></a>";
          }`

Comment: $(tr).find(".classdatddoicon").empty();
$(tr).find(".classdatddoicon").html("<a href='#'>remover</a>");
ai você informa o html do link que quer que apareça

Comment: $(tr).find(".classdatddoicon").empty();
$(tr).find(".classdatddoicon").html("<a href='#'>remover</a>");
ai você informa o html do link que quer que apareça

ou na hora que a pagina carregar você imprime os dois links so que ocultando um e mostrando o outro, ai quando executar essa funcao basta vc alterar o css do button dessa forma
$(tr).find(".classdatddoicon > .iconativar").hide();
$(tr).find(".classdatddoicon > .iconremover").show();
e no else faz o processo contrario. Lembrando que o link de ativar tem q ter a class iconativar e o de remover iconremover.

Comment: Coloquei assim `$(tr).find(".ativar").empty(); $(tr).find(".banir").html("<a href='#'>remover</a>");` mas não deu certo. Caso preferir, vou sinalizar sua resposta como correta referente a pergunta anterior e abro outra pergunta sobre este assunto @Antony Alkmim

Comment: Dentro do  ´IF`, como que eu imprimo um ícone e oculto o outro? Acho que desta maneira ficaria mais fácil.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18478/discussion-between-rodrigo-segatto-and-antony-alkmim).